# Implement companion object / factory in a separate submodule

Tags: scala, sbt, companion-object

In my `core` sbt module, I have an trait `Matrix` for a matrix data type, and a trait `MatrixInstance` that has some factory methods. The companion object is supposed to extend this trait.

In a separate sbt submodule `implementation1`, I would like to implement this

```scala
object Matrix extends MatrixInstance { ... }
```

companion.

The idea here is that if I decide to have a second implementation, the library user could just change his `libraryDependencies += ...` from `implementation1` to `implementation2`.

However, this doesn't seem to work. i.e. it looks like an object and it's companion must reside in the same module (file?). Otherwise I get circular dependencies and scalac fails.

Is there any pattern I can use to achieve this functionality? i.e. define the interface trait for the factory/companion object, have it implemented in a separate artifact, and then allow the user to choose between the implementations by only changing `libraryDependencies`?

Answer (score 0):

If they must be in different files, just don't call it `Matrix`. You can name it, for example, `matrix`. It won't be a companion object, so it will not be included automatically in implicit search related to `Matrix`, but you can always import it if necessary.

As an example, both Scalaz and Cats have a `list` object that contains a number of type class instances and syntaxes for the stdlib `List`, e.g., https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.11/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala

Comment: Like you say, this is for type-classes that provide extension methods, i.e. functionality, rather than the data type itself. In cats for example you still write e.g. `Option(2)` to create the data type, not `option(2)`. What I'm trying to change here is the implementation of `Option` rather than it's algebra.

Comment: I don't think this is what you're suggesting, but it may be possible to create a typeclass that extends the original companion object. e.g. `implicit class MatrixImpl1(val companion : Matrix.type) { def apply() ...}` Dunno if that will work though (i.e. extending companion objects).